# A Netlogo Model of UAVs (being cognitive) for smart city or smart field

Tags: netlogo

Looking for a Netlogo-file to understand how an agent(UAV) interacts with another agent in monitoring purpose.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Your question is not very specific.  I recommend reading ["How to ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get an idea of how to ask a question people would be able to leave a good answer for.

Answer (score 0):

Sujan,  can you explain what kind of interaction you want to see?  There are 2000 models in the Modeling Commons,  and over 100 in the library:

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/index.cgi

You can try many of these over the web to see what they do, without downloading anything, and look at the code that runs the model, here:

http://www.netlogoweb.org/launch

Comment: I have read a paper linked is https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.10847 it states about adaptive intelligence with LevelSpace extensions to make sophisticated cognitive capabilities in the agent behavior in stead of random behavior used in ABMs stated in this paper. I want to see a model where agents have adaptive intelligence for understanding the scenario.